# Quirks / Bugs in Mailchimp Template's HTML

Tags: css, html, html-email, mailchimp

In my current job I manage a Mailchimp account and utilize templates created before I was hired -- by an outside firm. Currently, my email template prevents me from italicizing without changing the color of text. I'd like to be able to make the text italic, and keep the same text color. When looking at the code for the various fonts, nothing appears abnormal.

```
@section body text
@tip Set the styling for your email's main content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
@theme main
*/
    .bodyContent div{
        /*@editable*/color:#505050;
        /*@editable*/font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        /*@editable*/font-size:14px;
        /*@editable*/line-height:150%;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
        font-weight:normal !important;
    }
/*
@tab Body
@section body link
@tip Set the styling for your email's main content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
*/
    .bodyContent div a:link,.bodyContent div a:visited{
        /*@editable*/color:#336699;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .bodyContent img{
        display:inline;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    hr{
        color:orange;
        width:1px;
    }
    div.button{
        margin-left:-1px;
        margin-top:0px;
    }
    div.button a,div.button a:hover,div.button a:active,div.button a:visited{
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        background-color:#FE7702;
        height:25px;
        width:100px;
        font-weight:900 !important;
        font-size:19px;
        color:white !important;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        padding:10px;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin:10px 0 10px 0;
        border:2px solid;
        border-radius:25px;
    }
```

I think it may have to do with the '!important' directive, but I don't know where to find what it initially referenced. Any other ideas on where this quirk might be coded or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything in the given code referencing `em`, `i` or `text-style` either. It could be someplace else, but you can fix it by adding a little styling in the `em` tag inline:

```
<em style="color: inherit !important;">italics text!</em>
```

That should get you taken care of - if testing reveals "inherit" isn't working everywhere, just replace it with the proper color hex code.